# Copy/reference Text Box Date value from a form to a report in Access

Tags: vba

So I am working in an Access DB and this may be something i completely over looked.

How can I take the value from a form that's in a text box formatted for Dates and the reference that value on a report?

The dates aren't based of a query or anything it's something the user would have to input (ex. date the imported source date was created) and this should be added to the report output?

Is it possible to reference/copy a form text box's date value into a report's txt box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form where the TextBox was is still open, you can use the below to show the data in the report

```
=[Forms]![FORM_NAME]!TEXTBOX_NAME
```